# Authorize tag not triggering authentication in ASP.NET MVC5 WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application with WebAPI and Individual Accounts built with VS.2015 Community Edition.

I created the Identity database with Code Migrations and it has a default administrator user created in it.

I noticed that the Login link is no longer present in the MVC site (why?) and that all authentication seems to have moved to WebAPI.

Trying to figure things out I noticed there is a Values Controlled installed by the template that has the Authorize attribute applied to the entire controller thus requiring authentication.

I fired the MVC application and proceeded to request the /api/values/5 request which should cause the Get method of the VAlues Controller to fire IF the user is authenticated. Well, to my surprise when I use Postman to fire the GET request I get the return value given by the method without even being authenticated! In fact, since there is no Login I thought that perhaps any attempts to request a "protected" controller method would result in some sort of user authentication dialog but NOTHING, it simply returned the value as if the Authorize attribute was not there.